# Sentry add context react native

Tags: react-native, sentry

I am trying to use sentry to track logs and errors on my react native application

I just did a simple test to understand how to add context

```js
Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'https://***@***.ingest.sentry.io/***',
});
Sentry.setContext('foo', 'bar');
Sentry.captureException(new Error('test sentry error'));
```

My error is displayed in sentry but I can not see my extra context, I only have some undefined data in `ADDITIONAL DATA`

[image]

Comment: Are you using Expo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentry.setContext takes an object as a second parameter and not a string:
http://getsentry.github.io/sentry-javascript/classes/hub.scope.html#setcontext

In the docs here they have mistakenly put a string as an example.